# Average previous and next row for missing value

Tags: r, mean, missing-data

I'm relatively new to R and running into some issues. I'm working with a dataframe that has missing values in certain years. For example:

```
year var1 var2
1972 1.3  1.4
1973 1.6  2.8
1974 2.0  1.5
1975 NA   NA
1976 1.5  2.1
1977 NA   NA
1978 1.9  1.1
```

For each NA, I want to take the mean of the previous and next rows. So var1 and var2 in 1975 should be 1.75 and 1.8, respectively. In 1977 they should be 1.7 and 1.6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `na.approx` in the package `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
df$var1 <- na.approx(df$var1)
df$var2 <- na.approx(df$var2)
##
> df
  year var1 var2
1 1972 1.30  1.4
2 1973 1.60  2.8
3 1974 2.00  1.5
4 1975 1.75  1.8
5 1976 1.50  2.1
6 1977 1.70  1.6
7 1978 1.90  1.1
```

- As @Jilber pointed out, this can be done more concisely with

  ```
  df <- sapply(df, na.approx)
  ```
- Per @Richard Scriven's comment, you may want to preserve the
  `data.frame` class with

  ```
  df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], na.approx)
  ```

  or

  ```
  df[-1] <- vapply(df[-1], na.approx, numeric(nrow(df)))
  ```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(
  text="year var1 var2
1972 1.3  1.4
1973 1.6  2.8
1974 2.0  1.5
1975 NA   NA
1976 1.5  2.1
1977 NA   NA
1978 1.9  1.1",
  header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Another function to take home tonight. Thank you. +1

Comment: you can shorten your code by using `sapply`: `sapply(df, na.approx)`

Comment: Or `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], na.approx)` to keep it in a data frame. `sapply` returns a matrix

Comment: Another option.. `require(dplyr); df %>% mutate_each(funs(na.approx), -year)`

Comment: Or possible faster than `lapply` is `df[-1] <- vapply(df[-1], na.approx, numeric(nrow(df)))`, okay I'm done (+1)

Comment: or `as.data.frame(na.approx(DF))` Also, you might want to convert your data frame to a zoo object which is more convenient for dealing with time series: `library(zoo); z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = identity); na.approx(z)`